# Validate MAC address in C

Tags: c, validation

i need to verify that the given MAC address is valid or not.

I went through some links [How do you validate that a string is a valid MAC address in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792035/how-do-you-validate-that-a-string-is-a-valid-mac-address-in-c)

I followed steps as above but it is not working please help me.
Here is what i tried.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main(const char* mac) {
  int i = 0;
  int s = 0;
  mac = "11:11:11:11:11:11"

  while (*mac) {
    if (isxdigit(*mac)) {
      i++;
    }
    else if (*mac == ':' || *mac == '-') {
      if (i == 0 || i / 2 - 1 != s)
        break;
      ++s;
    }
    else 
      s = -1;
    ++mac;
  }
  return (i == 12 && (s == 5 || s == 0));
}
```

This code runs fine but i am not getting any output.
Please help me.

Comment: (1) You signature for main is non-standard, and I'm willing to bet it doesn't do what you expect it to do. (2) You program doesn't actually call any output routines!

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings.  Then fix what it tells you.

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to tell us *how* "it is not working".

Comment: Here's an idea: `if(sscanf(mac, "%*2x:%*2x:%*2x:%*2x:%*2x:%*2x") == 6) { printf("OK!\n"); `.

Comment: Ignoring the bugs in your main signature and not looking the logic. You are returning the result not printing. 
If you are on *NIX environment you can run echo $? after running the above code. 
On windows you can run echo %errorlevel%

Answer (score 1):

If you use the code from the link you gave as part of a *valid* C program then it will work. You need to go learn about input and output methods for C weather they be via stdio or passing arguments to, and handling return values from, `main()`

In *psuedo-code* this might look like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int isValidMacAddress(const char* mac);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    mac = get-input;
    result = isValidMacAddress(mac);
    output-result(result);
}

int isValidMacAddress(const char* mac) {
    int i = 0;
    int s = 0;

    while (*mac) {
        if (isxdigit(*mac)) {
            i++;
        } else if (*mac == ':' || *mac == '-') {
            if (i == 0 || i / 2 - 1 != s)
                break;
            ++s;
        }
        else {
            s = -1;
        }
        ++mac;
    }
    return (i == 12 && (s == 5 || s == 0));
}
```

Now the `get-input` part could request the user type, and subsequently read (research `scanf()`), some value at the console (standard input), or it could get the input from an argument given to `main()` when the program is called.

The `output-result` part could be simply returning the result to the calling environment, or it could be printing (research `printf()`) the value to the console (standard output).